# How do I get a collection of attribute values and products that use them?

Tags: attributes, collection, reports, eav, collection-filtering

I would like to run a report of attribute values used by a drop-down select attribute, e.g. colour, and the quantity of products that actually use them.

I can get the list of actually used attributes and their respective counts by using:

```
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributeId)
        ->groupByAttribute($attributeId)
        ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('instances', "COUNT({{entity_id}})", 'entity_id')
        ->setOrder($attributeId);
```

I can also get a complete list of values for a given attribute:

```
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeId);

    $valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
        ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
        ->setStoreFilter(0, false);
```

However, I have so far not been able to join these collections or find a better way of achieving what I want. In my list I would like the complete set of attribute values including the ones that are not used by any products. Furthermore, in my collection, I would also like the sort order numbers assigned to each attribute value. Plus the product count.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559166/magento-how-to-get-attribute-values-used-in-products ?

Comment: Tanatalising but not there!

Answer (score 4):

> including the ones that are not used by any products.

Then you need your attribute collection and `left join` the products. Left join is not supported by the collection `join()` method, so use the underlying `Zend_Db_Select`.

## Code

```
$attributeCode = 'color';

$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
$productResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');

// Use collection only to prepare query
$valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setStoreFilter(0, false);

// Now refine query
$valuesCollection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('value_table' => $productResource->getTable(array('catalog/product', 'int'))),
        'main_table.option_id=value_table.value AND main_table.attribute_id=value_table.attribute_id', 'entity_id')
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns(array('main_table.option_id', new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(value_table.entity_id)')))
    ->where('main_table.attribute_id=:attribute_id')
    ->group('main_table.option_id');

// ...and fetch data
$result = $productResource->getReadConnection()->fetchPairs(
    $valuesCollection->getSelect(), array('attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()));
```

Result now contains an array in the form `[option_id => number of products]`